# Upgrade weapon mechanics

Tags: dnd-4e

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can players use crafting to improve beloved magic items instead of churning gear?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/can-players-use-crafting-to-improve-beloved-magic-items-instead-of-churning-gear)

Are there any D&D 4.0 mechanics to upgrade weapons?

One of my PCs has a weapon that is part of his story.
As his character grows in power he is bound to "outgrow" it.
How can I offer a way to upgrade this particular weapon without having to replace it.

I'm thinking in the direction of enchantment/socketing etc.

Comment: If those questions are substantially different, please let me know.

Comment: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4766/810 is the question that I wrote that people think is a duplicate. I'm not sure why Stack Excange's close-as-duplicate mechanism doesn't seem to require a pointer to the duplicated and imbed it in the "closed" statement.

Comment: Bizare. Stackoverflow does have that mechanic I think.

Comment: I think it has a mechanic that gives option to provide a pointer, but may not mandate it - particularly in this case, where the close was executed by a moderator.

Comment: @F. Randal Farmer Actually it does, require a pointer (even for mods), and it adds a link to that question to the top of the question as `Possible Duplicate`.  It is confusing because it's at the top, not the bottom, with `Closed`.